# WindowsForms - How to cast an integer to String in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and I am creating a Form that is supposed to give the user the opportunity to enter name and age. Then, by submitting this information, there should be a summary(a new form) that shows what the user their input.
I finally got it working with the name, as it's a string and it's not a big deal, but I am stuck with the age.
I've tried casting, however, it does not work. I also looked at the documentation, but I do not find anything useful. Well, probably because I don't know where to look. 
Anyway, I would strongly appreciate if someone give me an example for this.
Thanks in advance.

**FormEnterDetails.cs**

```
PersonStatic.LName = this.textBoxLastName.Text;
PersonStatic.Age = this.textBoxAge.Text;
```

**DetailsHolder.cs**

```
private string lName;
public string LName
{
    get { return lName; }
    set { lName = value; }
}

string age;
public String Age
{
    get { return age; }
    set { age = value; }
}
```

**FormSummary.cs**

```
private void FormSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //we need to do this work on form load and not on creation
    this.labelFirstNameSummary.Text = dh.FName;
    this.labelLastNameSummary.Text = dh.LName;
    this.labelAge.Text = Int32.Parse(dh.Age);
}
```

**PersonStatic.cs**

```
static string lName;

public static string LName
{
    get { return PersonStatic.lName; }
    set { PersonStatic.lName = value; }
}

static string age;
public static string Age
{
    get { return PersonStatic.age;}
    set { PersonStatic.age = value; }
}
```

Comment: Well typically you'd just put `.ToString()` on the end of whatever you want to cast to a `string`, so in this case `int myInt = 0; string theString = myInt.ToString();`. Without seeing any code at all it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong as representing the age as an integer shouldn't cause any issues and casting it to a string seems redundant.

Comment: Don't convert from int to a string, use `ToString()` to get it's string representation. For getting an int value from a string, use `int.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've posted, all places related to age appear to already be using `string`, not `int` (note that these are keywords that shorten the real type names, `System.String` and `System.Int32`). So you should be getting an error on this line:

```
this.labelAge.Text = Int32.Parse(dh.Age);
```

The [`Int32.Parse` static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_) converts *from* a `string` *to* an `int`. (If you want to convert the other way, then as other answers have mentioned, you can call the `ToString()` instance method on your `int`.)

But in this case `dh.Age`, assuming `dh` is an instance of `DetailsHolder`,  **is already** a `string`. And [`labelAge.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.text?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_Label_Text), assuming `labelAge` is an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.Label`, is also a `string`. So you don't need to do any conversion:

```
this.labelAge.Text = dh.Age;
```

Comment: BTW, you can look up framework-provided types, like `Label`, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/).

Answer (score 7):

I hope you want something like this

```
string ageString = ageInt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ToString()` built-in function to convert anything to a string:

```
Int x=5;
String y;
y=x.ToString();
```